# C# Recommendations for the best way to write text to a file such that if opened in notepad the user wont understand it

Tags: c#, encryption, text

Looking for recommendations for a simple way to write a string to a file so that the resulting file would not be readable/editable in Notepad.  I thought about using some serious encryption, but I think that is just over kill for what I need.  Just looking for a easy unreadable text format to convert to and from.

Comment: Weird question...

Comment: Really you can open just about any file in notepad, so maybe you should make your question more clear. If you're trying to obfuscate the data in the file, then encryption is probably your only option.

Comment: What you're talking about **is** encryption, even if it is done in a simple way.

Comment: You could do some dumb encryption like bitwise rotating all the characters by bitsize/2.

Comment: @Mehrdad doesn't seem that weird to me, sounds like the OP just wants to prevent users from screwing up the app.config, and @Tony Casale it's only encryption if he encrypts it in some way. Converting it to Base64 would not be encrypting it, that would be obfuscating it, similar to storing it as binary. You're not encrypting it, you're obfuscating it from standard text editors.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could Base64 encode it:

```
 string text = "My quasi secret text.";

 byte[] buffer = System.Text.UTF8Encoding.GetBytes(text);

 string protectedText = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);

 File.WriteAllText(filename, protectedText)
```

**EDIT:**  Updated to UTF8Encoding to handle unicode.

Comment: This should use one of the Unicode encodings instead of ASCII.

Answer (score 4):

How about using a binary formatter to serialize it?

That would pretty well ensure that people opening the file in Notepad would just end up with gobbledegook. But (it had to be said) if you attach any importance to people not being able to see or mess with this data, it needs to be truly encrypted.

Comment: +1 this is the correct option, if you don't want your file directly readable store it in binary.

Comment: I would argue that this is _an_ option, not _the_ option.

Comment: Thanks I might do this as well.

Answer (score 3):

Google translate it into French then translate it back. This won't work if your users speak French.

Comment: @Chris Marisic: What, you don't like French?

Comment: Funny, but I dont want to convert the text to another language.  But a good out of the box idea.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

If it doesn't need to be encrypted, then I would suggest Convert.ToBase64String/Convert.FromBase64String.

Simple and reliable.

Comment: MD5 hash the string then run the result against a rainbow table to find a matching input then use a web service to call your phone to tell you the answer?

Comment: Not worried about real hackers, just the average user reading and changing.  Thanks this will work.

Answer (score 1):

encryption, or maybe encoding (e.g. Base64 encoding? - or even a simpler one?). This would make it non readable, but still editable.

Comment: Not worried about editing, I just want to tell if the user did edit it.

Answer (score 1):

Something super simple would be [Base64 encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string.aspx):

`Convert.ToBase64String();`

Comment: I like this, I think this is what I am going to do.

Answer (score 1):

Encryption: to put (a message) into code or to distort so that it cannot be understood without the appropriate decryption equipment

By definition, you are trying to encrypt the data. The only difference is you only need an encryption that's strong enough to not allow laymen from accessing it's contents.

Like others have mentioned, using Base64 would effectively encrypt the data against your average user.

Comment: Your right, I should have phrased that better.  Thanks for the reply.

Answer (score 0):

So in the end here is what I did.

TO Write the data:

```
            //Write the text in a way the user wont recognize if they open the file in notepad.
            byte[] buffer = System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);
            string protectedText = Convert.ToBase64String(buffer);
            File.WriteAllText(UserToUserLevelDataFile, protectedText);
```

TO Read the data:

```
            string longText = File.ReadAllText(UserToUserLevelDataFile);
            data = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(Convert.FromBase64String(longText));
```

Works like a charm, thanks everyone for your ideas!

Comment: You can even apply ROT13 http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13 before (or after) converting to Base64 for a bit stronger obfuscation.